# Objective-C property alias

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, properties

Let's say that `ParentClass` has a string property called `a`:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *a;`

In a subclass `ChildClass`, I want the property `b` to be an alias for `super.a`. Meaning `b` does not really hold any value in itself, it just points to `a`.
If the value of `a` changes, then it should be reflected in `b`, and vice-versa.

What the the cleanest way to achieve this in Objective-C.

Comment: You could write yourself a getter for `b` that points to `a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do aliases, as such.  However, properties are just short-hand for method implementations.  Subclasses inherit (visible) properties of their superclass(es), so you can do something like the following:

```
- (void)setB:(NSString *)b {
    self.a = b;
}

- (NSString *)b {
    return self.a;
}
```

If `a` is not visible to the subclass, you have to do something like this:

```
- (void)setB:(NSString *)b {
    [self setValue:b forKey:@"a"];
}

- (NSString *)b {
    return [self valueForKey:@"a"];
}
```

This works because there's no type-checking at runtime, so if the property exists (with the standard names for the getter and setter), you can still use KVC to manipulate it.

Comment: It's best to add explanation along with the code, as otherwise it may be deleted.