# Can I give a property an alternate key name in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, kvc

Can I give a property in an Objective-C class an alternate name so that I can set the property using a different key than it's property name? Here is some example code.

```
@interface Address : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *apartmentNumber;
@end

// ...

Address *address = [Address new];
address setValue:@(123) forKey:@"apartmentNumber"];
```

Is it possible to access this property using an alternate key name like `"apt"`?

```
Address *address = [Address new];
[address setValue:@(123) forKey:@"apt"];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Objective-C property alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315713/objective-c-property-alias)

Comment: It helped! I wrote an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the feedback this seems to work without having to write any additional methods.

```
@interface Address : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic, getter=apt, setter=setApt:) NSNumber *apartmentNumber;
@end
```

Comment: Could have found that out by reading my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_property_declaration_syntax Note that you now have no `apartmentNumber` methods (getter or setter), which could cause trouble later if someone tried to call one of those explicitly. So this is not an "alternate" name; it is _the_ name. The advantage of Gerd K's approach is that you now have _both_ names.

Comment: Thanks for the link! It does work like this whether I refer to the property as `self.apt` or `self.apartmentNumber` or even by the key name `apt` or `apartmentNumber`.

Comment: Yup, you're right! I have no idea why that is. :) Another thing I notice is that for Swift interoperability, this property appears as `apartmentNumber`, not `apt`. You might not care about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a custom setter method:

```
- (void)setApt:(NSNumber *)apt {
    
    self.apartmentNumber=apt;
}
```

And a getter if needed:

```
- (NSNumber *)apt {
    
    return self.apartmentNumber;
}
```